# How to configure Bluetoothctl agent for Out-Of-Band pairing

Tags: bluetooth

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and need to enable out-of-band pairing with bluetoothctl. I looked at the possible options for agent capability but out-of-band seems is not supported.

I have a USB tag reader ACR-122U connected to the system.

I tried bt-agent. But that also does not seem to support out-of-band.
Any tips?
Thanks in advance